# how to get dom element from jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, dom, selector, handler

How can I target the elements that match such condition?

I've got the next code:

```
if($(".class").is(':visible') && !$(".class").hasClass('match_group')){
/// target those elements with that specific condition, the goal I wanna reach implies doing things like for example:

$(".class").is(':visible').css({'background-color':'blue'}):

//or even better attatch a event handler if posssible
}
```

I another forum someone recomended me to use `.closest()` and put conditions in it but I don't know how

Comment: Do you mean to say - all visible elements with class name `class`, without the class `match_group` to have a background of `blue` ?

Comment: what about $(".class").not(".match_group").is(":visible")

Comment: Yes that's what I mean